# Как отследить перелистывание в Pager (accompanist)

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Я использую Pager с ScrollableTabRow, и из-за того что в ScrollableTabRow вкладки уходят за экран, его индикатор тоже уходит за экран при перелистывании Pager'а, как я могу отследить перемещение на другую страницу, чтобы вызвать перелистывание самих вкладок и некоторую другую логику?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    val selectedTabIndex = remember { mutableStateOf(currentDay) }
    val selectedTabTitle = remember { mutableStateOf(tabTitles[currentDay].title) }
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(currentDay)

    //нужно вызвать этот метод
    fun selectTab(index: Int){
        selectedTabIndex.value = index
        selectedTabTitle.value = tabTitles[index].title
    }



                ScrollableTabRow(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(bottom = 10.dp, top = 15.dp),
                    contentColor = light_shaded,
                    selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex.value,
                    edgePadding = 0.dp,
                    indicator = { tabPositions ->
                        TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                            Modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset(
                                pagerState,
                                tabPositions
                            )
                        )
                    },
                    ) {
                    tabTitles.forEachIndexed { index, s ->
                        Tab(
                            text = {
                                Text(
                                    text = s.title.uppercase(Locale.getDefault()),
                                    fontSize = 18.sp
                                )
                            },
                            selected = selectedTabIndex.value == index,
                            onClick = { selectTab(index) },
                            modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp),
                        )
                    }

                }


                //текст привязан к selectedTabTitle
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = 20.dp, start = 35.dp),
                    text =  "${selectedTabTitle.value}, " +
                            "${TimeManager.getWeekDates()[0][selectedTabIndex.value]} " +
                               TimeManager.getWeekDates()[1][selectedTabIndex.value].capitalize(),
                    fontSize = 23.sp,
                    color = primary_color,
                    maxLines = 1,
                )


                    
                    HorizontalPager(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .wrapContentHeight()
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(top = 70.dp),
                        count = tabTitles.size,
                        state = pagerState,
                        contentPadding = PaddingValues(start = 15.dp),
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
                    ){ tabIndex ->
                        LazyColumn(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding( end = 15.dp, )//start = 15.dp, top = 70.dp
                            ,
                        ){
                            items(
                                state.schedule[tabIndex]//tabIndex selectedTabIndex.value
                                    .filter { it.dayDate != viewModel.weekParity.oppositeShortName }
                            ){ subject ->
                                SubjectItem(subject)
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну технически у вас есть `tabIndex->` и при смене страницы вы можете внутри блока отслеживать изменение и вызывать `selectTab()`, с защитой от рекомпозиций, то есть городить костыли...

Но в jetpack compose используются состояния. Меняется состояние - происходит рекомпозиция. Нужно следить только за состоянием. И я бы сделал вроде такого.

```
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    //чтобы вылезло за экран
    val tabs = listOf(
        "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
        "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
        "cccccccccccccccccc",
        "dddddddddddddd",
        "eeeeeeeeeeeeeee",
        "fffffffffffffff",
        "gggggggggggggg"
    )
    Column() {
        ScrollableTabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage
        ) {
            tabs.forEachIndexed { index, textVal ->
                Tab(
                    selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                    onClick = {
                        scope.launch { pagerState.scrollToPage(index) }
                    }) {
                    Text(
                        text = textVal,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        HorizontalPager(state = pagerState, count = tabs.size) { page ->
            Text(
                text = tabs[page],
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```